# confusion over using transient or scoped or singleton in .NetCore

Tags: asp.net-core

Hey Guys i'm very new in software development,I still no idea when to use which,whats the meaning of service lifetime!it may seem stupid but please help me,i have an interface :

```
 public  interface IAccessInfo
{
    public IEnumerable<AccessInfo> getResult();
}
```

what it supposed to do is to returns me the information about my Turbines;here is the implementation of it :

```
 public class AcessInfoData:IAccessInfo
{
    private DbContextClass db;
    public AcessInfoData(DbContextClass context)
    {
        db = context;

    }
    public IEnumerable<AccessInfo> getResult()
    {     
    var turbines = (from c in db.accessinf                         
                      where s.user_id == "i0004912"
                        select new AccessInfo
                        {
                            InfoType = c.type,
                            TurbineId = c.m_plc_id.ToString(),
                            TurbineIP = c.turbine_ip.ToString(),
                            TurbineIdSorting = c.turbine_id,
                            Blade = c.blade,
                            Certification = c.certification,

                       }).Distinct();

        return turbines;

    }
}
```

it gets an instance of my DB and gets the data;and in my controller i use it like this:

```
 public class AcessInfoController : ControllerBase
{

  private IAccessInfo _acess;
  public  AcessInfoController(IAccessInfo access)
    {
        _acess = access;       

    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var rsult = _acess.getResult();
        return Ok( rsult);
    }
}
```

now in the Startup i registered it :

```
  services.AddScoped<IAccessInfo, AcessInfoData>();
```

it works,but if you `sk` me why i user Scoped and not Singleton or transient i have no idea why,really,any one can make it clear for me?

Comment: I wrote an article quite a while ago about DI in .NET Core: https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-di-deep-dive it might give some info :)

Comment: @juunas i read that,but can you tell me which lifetime i should pick?in the aforementioned example?

Comment: If your DbContext is registered as Scoped (the default for EF Core), then your class here can be Scoped or Transient. It cannot be Singleton as that would be a higher lifetime than Scoped.

Comment: @juunas yes because if register as Singleton i get error!but can you tell me about this life time?what do you mean by higher lifetime?

Comment: @juunas if register all my services as a scoped ,it will cause problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain a little about the mentioned cases:

**scoped** : For all needs of an object during the life of an operation (such as a request from the client) a single instance of the object is created. `(It means that only one instance of the object is sent for all requirements during life time of a request)`

**Singleton**: Creates only one instance of object and sends it for all requirements in the application scope.`(For all needs everywhere in the program, only one instance of the object is sent, a bit like static objects)`.

**Transient**: Ioc container, makes an instance of object whenever code needs it, that is, it makes an instance for each requirement anywhere in the program and at any time, which means that if the program needs an object 3 times, it makes an independent instance for each.

**Instance**: In this case, each time an object is needed, only one instance of it is provided to the program, which you defined it in the startup section. (when defining it in the startup section, you specify how to create an instance).

I hope to reduce some of the ambiguities.

Comment: so in my example if i select Singleton ,what would happen?

Comment: This is very important, when you set the object as a singleton, in fact that object stays in the memory from the beginning of the program to the end of its execution, and the amount of memory consumption is important for the server.
Also, in most cases, we want to set an object from the beginning when an object is needed, but if we introduce it as a singleton this will not be possible, and so on.

Comment: @ilmagnifico, in your example, at the execute time, We may not see much change during run, but your object will remain in the server's memory from site starts to run to finishing execution. Consider defining all examples of different objects in this way, then you will fill the server's RAM. You're going to run RAM on server, but we're not always building sites for big computers.

Comment: so you mean,by registering service scoped im imposing load on the server right?

Comment: No, we have to learn from experience which objects are good for scoped and which ones we need to create singleton. in many cases scoped is a better option.

Comment: Does each request create a new instance of the controller?

Comment: @variable, You can test it by adding a breakpoint to the controller's constructor!